# Is there a way to only use certain data with the .describe() function in jupyter notebook without .drop

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a table with certain information but I have to get rid of some other information. I used .drop and it works but it also messes up the other graphs I made after. Is there a way to get rid of the information without using .drop or messing up the tables after it.

```py
heart_failure = heart_failure.drop(['anaemia', 'diabtes', 'ejection_fraction', 'high_blood_pressure', 'platelets', 'sex', 'smoking', 'DEATH_EVENT'], axis=1)

heart_failure.describe()
```

This works but messes up the data after

Comment: Why reassign the `heart_failure` dataframe the way you do? You probably want to [make a copy first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) so the drop steps don't affect your `heart_failure` dataframe and it remains intact? `heart_failure_dfcleaned = heart_failure.copy()`. A deep-copy is the default. Then do your drops with the copy: `heart_failure_dfcleaned` = heart_failure_dfcleaned.drop([' .... And then use `heart_failure_dfcleaned.describe()`? (You may be able to skip the `.copy()` assigning; however, I haven't tested and so leaving it to be sure.)

Comment: Did you try it without the copy step or kept it to be sure? The drop is supposed to default to not be in place and so I don't think it is necessary. But you definitely wanted to keep the source intact and so you needed to reassign the drop step to a new object at any rate.

Comment: I kept the copy step just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

If the only use of the ridded data frame is to call `describe()` on it, there's no need for an assignment.

```
heart_failure.drop([…], 1).describe()
```